# Good practice: unused properties for backend purposes

Tags: backend, software-design

It's a beginner question in software design.
I have a class like this

```
ProductProperty
----------------
+product_property_id:int
+values:array
+current_value:string
```

In frontend scenario I use this class to model a product and its properties with possible values (values is an array of strings) and the selected value (current_value holds a specific string stored in values).

And in backend? Should I use different classes there? I mean I use this class to create new products with properties. I instantiate an object like `new ProductProperty(435, NULL, bla, bar, bah)` to create and store an Object like

```
{
 id:435,
 values:['bla','bar','bah'],
 current_value:NULL
}
```

and never use the current_value-Property.

To store an order for example of course I populate the current_value-property but do not really use the values array instead.

Is it fine that way or do I have to create separate classes for each case.

Comment: it is fine. why do you think it wouldn't be?

Comment: maybe a professional would say it's too hacky, because he user different classes like an extended class "ProductPropertyChoice" or something. Don't know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good practice is to employ a pattern like Value Object (VO) or Data Transfer Object (DTO). It means that you must create another class only with the properties that you are transferring from a layer to another. I see that it is required and useful in cases much more complex than in your example. The system maintaining effort considering many classes for the same entity tends to be much higher than using a class full of empty properties, because computational power is way cheaper than programmer hour rate.

Check this article about the difference: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/value_object_vs_data_transfer

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object